# How to properly read line using sockets through asynchronous callback

Tags: c#

I have a library that is connected to some network service using TCP sockets and randomly receives a data from it. I need to process these data line by line and for that I have 2 options:

**Create a new thread** (I don't want to do that) in which I have never ending loop which calls `StreamReader.ReadLine()` (I don't want to spawn new threads as this is a library and threads should be fully under control of main program)

**Using async callback which gets called every time some data arrives to stream buffer**. I currently use this option, but I am having troubles getting lines only. I hacked out this simple solution:

```
    // This function reset the callback after it's processed
    private void resetCallback()
    {
        if (this.networkStream == null)
            return;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.lineBuffer) && this.lineBuffer.EndsWith("\n"))
        {
            this.processOutput(this.lineBuffer);
            this.lineBuffer = "";
        }
        AsyncCallback callback = new AsyncCallback(OnReceive);
        this.networkStream.BeginRead(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, callback, this.networkStream);
    }

    // This function gets called every time some data arrives to buffer
    private void OnReceive(IAsyncResult data)
    {
        if (this.networkStream == null)
            return;
        int bytes = this.networkStream.EndRead(data);
        string text = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, bytes);
        if (!text.Contains("\n"))
        {
            this.lineBuffer += text;
        }
        else
        {
            List<string> parts = new List<string>(text.Split('\n'));
            while (parts.Count > 0)
            {
                this.lineBuffer += parts[0];
                if (parts.Count > 1)
                {
                    this.processOutput(this.lineBuffer + "\n");
                    this.lineBuffer = "";
                }
                parts.RemoveAt(0);
            }
        }
        this.resetCallback();
    }
```

As you can see I am using very nasty solution where I am basically checking in every "packet" of data that are received on buffer:

- Whether data in buffer are whole line (ends with new line)
- Whether data in buffer contains more than 1 line (new line is somewhere in middle of data, or there are more than 1 new line)
- Data in buffer contains only a part of a line (no new line in text)

The problem here is that callback function can be called any time when some data are received, and these data can be a line, part of a line, or even multiple lines.

Based on the new line I am storing data in another buffers and when I finally get a new line, I process it somehow.

This is actually working just fine, but I am still wondering if there isn't a better solution that is more clean and doesn't require such a hacking in order to read the stream line by line without using threads?

Comment: The code is also broken in assuming that any sequence of bytes received can be turned into a valid UTF8 string. There's no guarantee given by TCP that you won't receive a set of bytes including *part* of a multi-byte character (where the remaining bytes of that character will probably arrive the *next* time you make a read call)

Comment: I don't know where you got the idea that a library shouldn't spin up new threads.  It's perfectly acceptable to have a library spin up new threads because the library life-cycle is under the control of the application.

Comment: @Dan-o so this isn't easily doable without use of threads? I rarely see any 3rd libraries (like mysql lib etc) that connects somewhere using TCP to spawn new threads. It's not like I was saying it's really bad idea to do that, but having huge amount of threads in your app, for every single TCP connection is probably not a best thing

Comment: I'd do it differently. What is `\n`? It's combination of bytes `0xD`,`0xA`. In `OnReceive`  just check for those, while storing received previously **bytes**. Once you receive `0xD`,`0xA` - convert already received bytes into string, process it (as a line).

Comment: Well that's different.  Choosing the correct architecture is entirely dependent on use case.  My previous comment was just in regard to your assertion that spawning threads in a library was bad because "threads should be fully under control of main program".

Comment: @Sinatr yes, that is related to comment by Damien regarding broken code, I will do that to fix that bug, however I was wondering if there isn't more simple solution for this, something like asynchronous "read line" callback that would be called for each line, so that I wouldn't need to handle that myself

Comment: @Sinatr `\n` is `0xA`, `\r\n` is `0xD 0xA`.

Comment: @C.Evenhuis, it depends - *When writing a file in text mode, '\n' is transparently translated to the native newline sequence used by the system, which may be longer than one character* (from [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline)). Good comment if '\n` is exactly `LF` (not `CR+LF` as it is often).

Comment: @Sinatr for C# it does not depend, `\n` is `0xA`. For the system newline sequence you can use `Environment.NewLine`, but that is irrelevant to this question.

Comment: @C.Evenhuis, you are very strict in conclusions. Can you please prove that *for C#* (no sarcasm, I'd really like to know if it's that strict). If you search for `\n` **chars**, then it's `LF` and I totally agree with you, but if you search for `\n` in **strings**, then it *may* suddenly become `CR+LF` (two bytes).

Comment: @Sinatr Some stream implementations may have such a replacement feature (I recall something about the console stream), but that does not change the meaning of the `\n` inside a string. I'm afraid I can't prove it right now.

Comment: @Sinatr: nothing in .NET will convert `\n` to `\r\n` on output. The text you are quoting in that Wikipedia article is for the _C_ programming language and in particular the CRT library. It has nothing to do with the behavior of .NET (and in fact, note the comment regarding the behavior of Java, specifically calling out that it does _not_ convert... .NET is a lot more like Java than it is like C). Your claim is fairly vague, but there's nothing in C# or .NET where you could write the literal escape `\n` in a string and it would implicitly become `\r\n` instead.

Comment: @PeterDuniho, try to write `string test = "\n";` and see what **bytes** will it contains (compared to `char test = '\n';`). I am **not** talking about bytes, but about string, which may be generated on **other side** by using C# code like this `string send = "blablabla \n blablabla \n ...";`). I mean *confusion* what may come due to **what \n means**. But you are repeating same known by me (and hopefully by others) truth, rephrasing it differently, which makes me a bit upset. Am I not clear enough or what?

Comment: @Sinatr: did _you_ try exactly the experiment you are asking me to try? In .NET/C#, a `string` variable contains UTF16-encoded text. The string literal "\n" contains the _bytes_ `0x0A, 0x00`. No carriage return character would be added. If you mean anything other than that, you are incorrect. If you mean that, then yes...you are not clear enough, because it seems like you are writing something completely different.

Comment: @PeterDuniho, you are right. Example lack something, but I forgot what (perhaps some conversion). Screw me, I can't find what was that case, where I had `\n` converted to `\r\n`. Perhaps it was like this: some other language, in protocol specification stated `\n` (perfectly valid for that language), I am writing client on C# and getting CR+LF.. Perhaps something else, will stop confusing people =P

Answer (score 1):

Please note commenter Damien_The_Unbeliever's point about the issue with partial UTF8 characters. As he says, there's nothing in TCP that would guarantee that you only receive whole characters; a sequence of bytes in the stream can be interrupted at any point, including mid-character.

The usual way to address this would be to using an instance of a `Decoder` (which you can retrieve from the appropriate `Encoding` subclass, e.g. `Encoding.UTF8.GetDecoder()`). A decoder instance will buffer characters for you, returning only whole characters as they are available.

But in your case, there is a *much* easier way: use the `TextReader.ReadLineAsync()` method.

For example, here's an asynchronous method which will process each line of text read from the stream, with the returned task for the method completing only when the stream itself has reached the end (i.e. graceful closure of the socket):

```
async Task ProcessLines()
{
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(
        this.networkStream, Encoding.UTF8, false, 1024, true))
    {
        string line;

        while ((line = await reader.ReadLineAsync()) != null)
        {
            this.processOutput(line);
        }
    }

    // Clean up here. I.e. send any remaining response to remote endpoint,
    // call Socket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both), and then close the
    // socket.
}
```

You would call that (preferably awaiting the result in another `async` method, though that would depend on the exact context of the caller) from wherever you call `resetCallback()` now. Given the lack of [a good, *minimal*, *complete* code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) a more specific explanation than that can't be provided.

The key is that, being an `async` method, the method will return as soon as you call `ReadLineAsync()` (assuming the call doesn't complete immediately), and will resume execution later once that operation completes, i.e. a complete line of text is available and can be returned.

This is the standard idiom now in C# for dealing with this kind of asynchronous operation. It allows you to write the code practically as if you are doing everything synchronously, while the compiler rewrites the code for you to actually implement it *asynchronously*.

(As an aside: you may want to consider using the usual .NET conventions, i.e. Pascal casing, for method names, instead of the Java-style camel-casing. That will help readers more readily understand your code examples).